# What is min and max in an AWS lambda metrics statistics

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

We know that AWS lambda provides us Duration metrics which has three statistics Viz:

1. Duration Minimun
2. Duration Maximum
3. Duration Average
   [image]

But when I try to explore one of these statistics,I see each of them has parameters like below:

Period: 1 minute

Statistic:  Minimum

Unit:   Milliseconds

Min:    1,881

Max:    94,677

Average:    4,876

Sum:    268,182

Last value: 2,414

Last time:  2022-12-22 10:27:00 UTC

What is the min,max for every statistic here? It is not clear to me. Please help!!
[image]

Comment: *"What is the min,max for every statistic here?"* - there is only one metric here, the duration, and you see its min, max, average, sum, last value, etc. I do not understand what your question is.

Comment: When I hover over one of the statistics, for eg: Duration Minimum, I see the Min, Max parameters for each one of them. What is not clear to me is, why do we have these additional parameters for every statistics.

Comment: Why not? What do you care what the UI displays to you!? That information is there and CW computes the statistics for you. If you do not want to see them don't hover.

Comment: I want to know the Average execution time of my lambda function. What is the best way to check it? Right now I do it by going to the Duration Average, hovering over it and checking the Average parameter. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Metric data points are not individual samples but are aggregates of multiple samples. These statistics allow you to understand the distribution without having to store or analyze individual samples. If you want average then you can plot the average value. When you hover on it, it gives you the additional statistics about the aggregate that you are hovered over. In other words if you plot average, the stat shown when you hover over any data point is that stat for the distribution not for the current stat that is being plotted (it’s not the min of the average but the min for the metric for that point in time).